# How can I change the color of a scanned png and edit part of it out in illustrator cs6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, logo, cs6, crop

The image is in color with a white background. I want to make the image white with a colored background. I want to switch the colors (make image white and background the color of the current image. I also want to cut out (delete) the bottom part of the image. Is it plausible to do in Illustrator cs6 or should I just use photoshop? I want this to look like professional graphic. The image is a png.

Comment: While you could do this in Illustrator, at least to a degree... You should definitely use Photoshop for photo editing.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop is the proper tool to use when editing raster graphics - png, jpg, gif, tiff, (some) eps, (some) pdf, bmp, etc.

Illustrator is for vector graphics - (some) eps, ai, (some) pdf, svg, etc.

You should be using Photoshop for a PNG file.

Answer (score 0):

If the image has solid colors, AI's Image Trace function might be able to trace the image. Then you could put the colors to a color swatch, then swap the colors.